# How can I output a list of unique values from a list in Excel

Tags: excel

From a list of clients and staff who assign work hours against each client. I am trying to output a unique list with the summed hours against each client.

Here's the original table:

[image]

And here's what the output should be:

[image]

The reason I can't use a normal =SUMIF formula is that I don't know what the list will be each time. It changes. So I need a formula that outputs the unique values of the first list, then sums the hours against it.

Comment: Pivot table of SUMIF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PivotTable in E1 with `Client` for ROWS and Sum of `Hours` for VALUES makes far and away the most sense to me but an alternative is to aply Advanced Filter (DATA > Sort & Filter).

Check Copy to another location, List range: A:A, Copy to: E1, check Unique records only, OK. Then in F2 and copied down to suit:

```
  =SUMIF(A:A,H2,C:C)
```

Neither however is fully dynamic, though the PT can be refreshed with two clicks.